# A commutative ring with unity which is not a PIR has a non-trivial ideal generated by two elements which is not a principal ideal?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity which is not a principal ideal ring . Then is it true that $\exists 0\ne x,y \in R$ such that the ideal $\langle x, y \rangle$ is not a principal ideal ?

Comment: The ring of algebraic integers is a counterexample.

Comment: @ZelosMalum: I am not an algebraist, so what am I missing? While the question is not among the brilliant ones, I do not find its answer obvious. We know that there are ideals that are not principal, but who guarantees that the ideals of the form $\langle x, y \rangle$ are among them?

Comment: @Servaes: We should not close questions based upon their mathematical content, we have downvoting for this. Closure should be decided on purely formal criteria. For me, from a purely formal point of view, this question is valid.

Comment: @Alex M.: I must agree, I have retracted my vote.

Comment: @Servaes: Besides this formal aspect, does this question really have an obvious answer (I am not an algebraist, as explained in a comment above)?

Comment: @Alex M.: My reaction was also rushed. The answer is indeed not entirely obvious. It seemed so to me, but I'm an algebraist.

Answer (score 3):

No it is not true. There exist rings which have the property finitely generated ideals are all principal. These are called Bezout rings.

There are such rings that aren't principal ideal rings, and any of those would be a counterexample to this proposition.

A specific example would be a nonprincipal von Neumann regular ring, like an infinite product of fields.